# Android: hide and show LinearLayout and EditText programatically

Tags: android

I have four EditText in a Linearlayout and a CheckBox.
Based on if else conditions and cheked/uncheked I want to hide and show them.
How can I do this programmatically? Thanks in advance for any help.

I used the code below but it not work for me when I cheked CheckBox.

```
CheckBox chkSetPos= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
          chkSetPos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {

                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {

                    layPos = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutPos);
                    layPos.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);             
                }
                else
                    layPos = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutPos);
                    layPos.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);                      
              }
            });
```

XML file:

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:text="@string/use_custom_position_fix"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutPos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lowerLeftX"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/lower_left_x_fix"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lowerLeftY"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/lower_left_y_fix"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/upperRightX"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/upper_right_x_fix"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/upperRightY"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/upper_right_y_fix"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your code that you have done until now

Comment: Can you post your full code. Depending which part of code is this, there seems nothing wrong with this code

Comment: Here I add the code of action on the CheckBox

Comment: Is Amadas answer working for you?

Comment: Sorry I tried this but it still not working. When I cheked on first time I get visible LinearLayout(EditText inside) but when I try to unchek nothing happened

Comment: I think either you are not checking the correct checkbox or hiding correct linearlayout.

Comment: No I cheked my code. Here I added XML file in my post.

Comment: Where is checkbox1 in the xml ?

Comment: Ok I added it in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Check out this
final LinearLayout search_bar=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
    CheckBox check=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked==true)
            {
                search_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            {
                search_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You try use onCheckedChangeListener instead onClickListener.

```
CheckBox chkSetPos= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
      chkSetPos.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (isChecked) {

                layPos = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutPos);
                layPos.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);             
            }
            else
                layPos = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutPos);
                layPos.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);                      
          }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Sorry I tried this but it still not working. When I cheked on first time I get visible LinearLayout(EditText inside) but when I try to unchek nothing happened

Comment: @user3383728 try print toast or log instead visible or gone. after this, is not working, add comment again. If toast is display, you do something wrong.

Comment: thanks for your attention I fixed my problem. I used TableLayout instead of LinearLayout in the solution proposed by Palak.